# How can I send two form fields, rather than the whole form to .serialize() ? Using Jquery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

I only want to send two fields to .serialize() and not the whole form. I want to send  `numberofwelds` and `numberofconwelds` (top two)  .

**My Form:**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="formsubmit" id="formsubmit"   >

    Number of welds: <input type="number" name="numberofwelds" id="numberofwelds"  >
    Number of construction welds: <input type="number" name="numberofconwelds" 
    id="numberofconwelds"  >

    Robot in/out: <input type="text" name="robotinout" disabled>
    Weld time: <input type="text" name="weldtime" disabled>
    Controlling cycle: <input type="text" name="concycle" disabled>
    Total time (secs): <input type="text" name="totaltimesecs" disabled>
    <input type="submit"  value="Calculate" id="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

**How to send the whole form.** I only want to send two fields not the whole form

```
var formData = $('#formsubmit').serialize();
$.get JSON ('calcsums.php', formData, sumresults);
```

How can I send just two fields?

Comment: create your own object to pass as data: `var formData = {numberofwelds: $('#numberofwelds').val(), numberofconwelds : $('#numberofconwelds').val()};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the serialize for only those input elements you want to serialize. If you want to serialize only numberofwelds and numberofconwelds then

```
var formData = $('#numberofwelds, #numberofconwelds').serialize();
$.get('calcsums.php', formData, sumresults);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mZnAJ/)

Comment: Why messing with the names? The fields have both an id.

Comment: @Andreas yes.. didn't focus on that

Answer (score 0):

Form .serialize() method will serialize all field of form you can change code as below to send only two fields

```
var formData = 'numberofwelds='+$('#numberofwelds').val()+'&numberofconwelds='+$('#numberofconwelds');
$.get('calcsums.php', formData, sumresults);
```